# Play Framework 2.5 WS post multipartform-data Writable

Tags: scala, playframework, multipartform-data

I would like to send multipart form data with WS call. I've tried to write a Writable to transform the request, but eventually I am receiving an empty body on requested host. Could you help me to fix my Writable. Here is my code:

```
 object MultipartFormDataWritable {
  val boundary = "----WebKitFormBoundary6s35viDB522LDEZQ"

  def formatDataParts(data: Map[String, Seq[String]]) = {
    val dataParts = data.flatMap { case (key, values) =>
      values.map { value =>
        val name = s""""$key""""
        s"--$boundary\r\n${HeaderNames.CONTENT_DISPOSITION}: form-data; name=$name\r\n\r\n$value\r\n"
      }
    }.mkString("")
    Codec.utf_8.encode(dataParts)
  }

  def filePartHeader(file: FilePart[TemporaryFile]) = {
    val name = s""""${file.key}""""
    val filename = s""""${file.filename}""""
    val contentType = file.contentType.map { ct =>
      s"${HeaderNames.CONTENT_TYPE}: $ct\r\n"
    }.getOrElse("")
    Codec.utf_8.encode(s"--$boundary\r\n${HeaderNames.CONTENT_DISPOSITION}: form-data; name=$name; filename=$filename\r\n$contentType\r\n")
  }

  val singleton = Writeable[MultipartFormData[TemporaryFile]](
   transform = { form: MultipartFormData[TemporaryFile] =>
      formatDataParts(form.dataParts) ++
        form.files.flatMap { file =>
          val fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file.ref.file.getAbsolutePath))
          filePartHeader(file) ++ fileBytes ++ Codec.utf_8.encode("\r\n")
        } ++
        Codec.utf_8.encode(s"--$boundary--")
    },
    contentType = Some(s"multipart/form-data; boundary=$boundary")
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you're not doing simply this?

```
ws.url(url).post(Source(FilePart("hello", "hello.txt", Option("text/plain"), FileIO.fromFile(tmpFile)) :: DataPart("key", "value") :: List()))
```

See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWS#submitting-multipart-form-data

Comment: My code working as a proxy, receiving request and directing with some Header updates.. So it's not only working for one customized request. I am trying to transform implicitly to support all body types

Comment: How to pass Multipe Data part in the request